# How to make two separate plots in seaborn from the same dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I have a dataframe in pandas that I'm trying to create two separate plots from in the same function, one is an ordinary boxplot w/ jitter and the other is a violin plot.

I've tried saving them to two separate variables and then saving each of those to their own image files, but in each of those files, the plots seem to contain an overlay of both of them rather than each containing their own separate plot. Here's what the code looks like:

```
final_boxplot = sns.boxplot(data = df)
final_violin = sns.violinplot(data = df)
final_boxplot.figure.savefig('boxplot.png')
final_violin.figure.savefig('violin.png')
```

any ideas on what I might be doing wrong, or any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create different instance of figures and
save:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
sns.boxplot(data=df, ax=ax)
fig.savefig('boxplot.png')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.violinplot(data=df, ax=ax)
fig.savefig('violin.png')
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try this... thanks for the help!